# Postgresql filtering by value over rolling time period

Tags: postgresql, query, timestamp

I am newbie to postgresql and still getting my head around. I have used windows function etc. till date and yes I can make some sense.

I have got the following data set:

[image]

I need to find those customers whose amount > 2 for 4 minutes in a rolling fashion, considering the data for a day. By that I mean in the given data set, customer 1 is one such as it has got amount > 2 at 16:01,16:02,16:03,16:04 and then at 16:02,16:03,16:04, 16:05. If there is any such single occurrence, the customer needs to be selected. Customer 2 doesn't have so. Wondering what's the best approach to do this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: It would be better if you provided the data as text, not screenshot. And if you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: *customers whose amount > 2 for 4 minutes in a rolling fashion* This means that ALL records within a priod have `amount > 2`? And - you say "for 4 minutes", but such period includes 5 values, not 4...

Comment: Also, regarding the details. Are all data in the table spaced by 1 minute? Or can it happen that you have rows with `16:00` and `16:01`, then more with `16:03` and `16:04` and what should happen in that case? Does the all > 2 count or not, when the `16:02` is missing?

Comment: hi @Akina, yes ALL records within a period have amount > 2. Not sure what you mean by 'but such period includes 5 values, not 4'. Do you mean you start at 16:00 and you scan till 16:04, you start at 16:01 and you scan till 16:05. I think yes makes sense

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, here is the create statement:

CREATE TABLE sales
(
  customer    BIGINT,
  purshase_ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  amount      NUMERIC
);

Comment: hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ, yes there can be interval without being 1 min. So say customer 3 can have records at 16:00, 16:05, 16:10.....16:20. So basically we need to check whether the amount > 2 starting from 16:00 till 16:05 ( 2 readings), starting from 16:05 till 16:10 ( 2 readings) because the gap between 2 reads is 5 which is greater than 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

Schematically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE t2.purshase_ts BETWEEN t1.purshase_ts AND t1.purshase_ts + INTERVAL 4 minute
  AND t1.customer = t2.customer
GROUP BY t1.customer, t1.purshase_ts
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.amount > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t2.amount)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.purshase_ts BETWEEN t1.purshase_ts AND t1.purshase_ts + INTERVAL 4 minute
                    AND t1.customer = t2.customer
                    AND t2.amount <= 2)
```

If time roll is to be "full", use 1st query adding relevant restriction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE t2.purshase_ts BETWEEN t1.purshase_ts AND t1.purshase_ts + INTERVAL '4 minute'
  AND t1.customer = t2.customer
GROUP BY t1.customer, t1.purshase_ts
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.amount > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t2.amount)
   AND COUNT(t2.amount) = 5
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE t2.purshase_ts BETWEEN t1.purshase_ts AND t1.purshase_ts + INTERVAL '4 minute'
  AND t1.customer = t2.customer
GROUP BY t1.customer, t1.purshase_ts
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.amount > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t2.amount)
   AND MAX(t2.purshase_ts) - MIN(t2.purshase_ts) = INTERVAL '4 MINUTE'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7114f7b19e0670ffb0abdb56a3c59471)

Comment: Suppose I have the following data:

customer,purshase_ts,amount
1,2018-12-18 16:00:00.000000 +11:00,2
1,2018-12-18 16:01:00.000000 +11:00,2
1,2018-12-18 16:02:00.000000 +11:00,1
1,2018-12-18 16:03:00.000000 +11:00,3
1,2018-12-18 16:04:00.000000 +11:00,5
1,2018-12-18 16:05:00.000000 +11:00,5
2,2018-12-18 16:00:00.000000 +11:00,2
2,2018-12-18 16:05:00.000000 +11:00,2
2,2018-12-18 16:10:00.000000 +11:00,4

If I run the either of the above queries, I get both 1 and 2. That is not correct as none of the customers has got amount > 2 for rolling 4 minutes

Comment: @app_developer That IS correct. For example, customer 1 have amount > 2 for rolling 4 minutes within period from 16:03 till 16:07. Of course, the data for 16:06 and 16:07 is absent in a table, but I do NOT see any restrictions of absent points.

Comment: @app_developer "Full pack" restrictions added - check.

Comment: I reckon the updated query only works if the purshahe_ts interval is 1 min. With the query below:

SELECT DISTINCT t1.customer
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE t2.purshase_ts BETWEEN t1.purshase_ts AND t1.purshase_ts + INTERVAL '4 minute'
  AND t1.customer = t2.customer
GROUP BY t1.customer, t1.purshase_ts
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.amount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t2.amount)
   AND MAX(t2.purshase_ts) - MIN(t2.purshase_ts) = INTERVAL '4 MINUTE'

I expect to see both 1 and 2. Because for 2, just considering the first 2 records, amount is > 1 for 5 mins which is greater than 4 mins

Comment: @app_developer Do not post code in comments - it's unreadable... Edit fiddle and post link to it.